# Kotlin and Generic Return Type with Springs ResponseEntity

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

Lets say I have a controller method in Spring with Kotlin and I want to return either a `ResponseEntity<Test>` or `ResponseEntity<Error>`.

How can I make this work in Kotlin? I have tried to put `ResponseEntitiy<Any>` or `ResponseEntity<*>` but Kotlin always complains.

**So how to make the return type truly Generic??**

```
@GetMapping
fun test(): Mono<ResponseEntity<?????>>
{
    return Mono.just(1)
        .map { ResponseEntity.ok(Test("OK") }
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Error("Error"))))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the body as well to give the correct type for each call:

```
fun test(): Mono<ResponseEntity<*>> {
    return Mono.just(1)
        .map { ResponseEntity.ok(Test("OK")) as ResponseEntity<*> }
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Error("Error")) as ResponseEntity<*>))
}
```

Alternately,

```
fun test(): Mono<ResponseEntity<Any>> {
    return Mono.just(1)
        .map { ResponseEntity.ok<Any>(Test("OK")) }
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body<Any>(Error("Error"))))
}
```

If `ResponseEntity` was written in Kotlin, it could probably be covariant and simplify the `Any` case, but it isn't.

(Note: I can't test at the moment, so these may need some fixes)

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. Works like a charm! Only the second `as ResponseEntity<*>` in the switchIfEmpty case was not necessary.